# Fourier transform on graphs

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I would like to know by some (rather simple) real examples of graphs,  how the Fourier  transform processes the graph.  Indeed, what exactly information is extracted (figured out) by computation of the eigenvalue of the corresponded Laplacian matrix.